# how i can upgrade powershell on windows server 2008 NOT R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008

how i can upgrade powershell on windows server 2008 NOT R2?
I can't found an upgrade for powershell for powershell on this server.
Current powershell version is the default one.
The OS on the server is MS® Windows Server® 2008 Standard 64-bit    ver. 2008 6.0.6002

Comment: Download whatever version of the “Windows Management Framework” that will run on your server.

Comment: 2.0 is probably the last version supported in non R2 server 2008....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968929/windows-management-framework-windows-powershell-2-0-winrm-2-0-and-bits

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade to the latest version of Powershell compatible with your operating system you can download and install the "[Windows Management Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf-overview)."

According to the compatibility chart, the newest version you can download and install on Windows Server 2008 SP2 is the [Windows Management Framework 3.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595).

This will upgrade you from the default Powershell version of v1.0 to v3.0.

**Update March 31st, 2024**

WMF versions older than 5.0 are no longer supported or available for download from Microsoft.